# CSRF token mismatch Laravel sanctum and Angular http

Tags: angular, laravel, http, laravel-sanctum

I have been trying to implement Laravel sanctum, but I am having this error "CSRF token mismatch" even though I followed everything that is said in the Laravel Sanctum documentation

`cors.php` config file

```php
'paths' => [
    'api/*',
    'login',
    'logout',
    'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
],
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

kernal is added as per the documentation, so not wasting space by adding its code here

`.env` file

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost
```

I am using Angular 9 as my frontend here

This is my interceptor

```js
request = request.clone({
    withCredentials: true
})
```

This is how I send the request to Laravel

```js
this.http.get<any>(url('sanctum/csrf-cookie')).subscribe(() => {
     this.http.post<any>(url('login'), { this.username, this.password })
         .subscribe(success => console.log(success), error => console.log(error))
})
```

Once the first route is hit I can confirm the creation of cookies, but the issue is with the second route ('/login')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send [x-csrf-token](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) in the header, (Angular includes it automatically only in relative URLs not absolute)

You can create an interpreter to do this, something like this should work:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpXsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';

  constructor(private tokenService: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'HEAD') {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    const token = this.tokenService.getToken();

    // Be careful not to overwrite an existing header of the same name.
    if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(this.headerName)) {
      req = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set(this.headerName, token)});
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I use that in my HttpClient post request?

Answer (score 14):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding `http://` before `localhost` in `config/sanctum.php`

From this

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env(
        'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
        'localhost,127.0.0.1'
)),
```

To this

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env(
            'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
            'http://localhost,127.0.0.1'
    )),
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem in my case but only some users are having this problem. I solved my problem by changing **SESSION_DOMAIN** to `.localhost` in the **session.php** file under the config folder.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was accessing the api on port 8001. It worked when I add it (127.0.0.1:8001) to 'stateful' in config/sanctum.php.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this problem was solved in a strange way. I went to the
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken file and there on line 76 in the "handle" method inside the "if case" there was a line like this:

```
$this->tokensMatch($request);
```

For testing purposes, I returned this string

```
return response()->json($this->tokensMatch($request));
```

and surprisingly it will return a normal token. Then I returned everything to its place, and it is strange, but this error was no longer there.